# gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I am using Kepller eclipse and I have `C++` and `C` projects on that. I have no problem in compiling and running `C++` projects, but when I create a `C` project, I see this error.

```
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

the whole message is:

```
23:46:32 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\MinGW\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\HelloWorld.o" "..\\src\\HelloWorld.c" 
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

23:46:32 Build Finished (took 416ms)
```

I have set the path variable as `C:\MinGW\bin`
is there anybody who can help me.

Comment: So it doesn't find `gcc`.. You should tell it where it is in the toolchain settings.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how I can tell it?

Comment: It might be helpful to share your makefile if you have one.